# Is it possible to test a Note 4 NFC antenna

Tags: nfc, samsung-galaxy-note-4

NFC has stopped working on my Note 4 (N910G).  As I understand it, the NFC antenna is embedded in the battery - it seems to be, I can see an antenna.

I am using an Anker replacement battery, but NFC has worked in the past with this battery.

Is there a way that I can check the antenna is working - that it is picking up a response?  Is there a way to get a raw readout of what the NFC chip is seeing?

Comment: This proved to be an issue with the battery - another one has NFC working fine.  But I'd still be interested to hear if there are ways to work out if nfc is working or not.

Comment: I recently replaced my Note4 with the Anker battery and I can't get NFC to work either. Did you ever find a fix?